# Deploying Web APP (Client side) as Desktop Client

Tags: javascript, rich-internet-application, qooxdoo

i am looking for an option to fully deploy the client side AJAX app written in js using qooxdoo framework.All view logic stays at Qooxdoo JavaScript framework. But i want to deploy it as desktop client too.

It already hosted on server and working fine but just to avoid Download time (JavaScript alone is 2 MB ) i also want to distribute as desktop client.

what i am looking for are :

1. Should work in Mac , Linux, and Windows and possibly android
2. Browser controls are unnecessary (location bar etc)
3. Should be able to run eval coz qooxdoo use eval selectively which make adobe air unable to work .

I know how to do in Xulrunner but I would prefer to do host it inside google chrome. I also finding a way to bundle xulrunner in portable way (is that already portable?can just download and run directly?)

EDIT: I looked Prism and its promising but is there anyway to bundle Client Side Web Content in a web bundle for Prism ? From its descrpition on Mozilla Wiki , we can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) looks like a viable option for packaging the entire application.  I haven't used it and have only recently [found out about it](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/creating-desktop-applications-with-node-webkit).

[Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) is an option, however there are some restrictions when using it.  Some have [successfully](http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/Titanium-Appcelerator-based-iOS-app-using-qx-oo-js-1-6-online-in-app-store-td7167429.html) used the qx-oo (just the OO layer) with Appcelerator.  Search "qooxdoo appcelerator" for more information.  There may be issues when using it with the qooxdoo UI layer (which is likely the whole point of your using qooxdoo.

Lastly, one "low tech" option might be to save the web page to your local computer via your web browser and then re-distribute those saved files as the "app."  I'd expect lots of problems with this, though.  For example, if you're dynamically loading different components in qooxdoo these scripts might not be saved.  It's easy enough to try, though.

Comment: Is there any Chrome based RIA like Prism ? I am mostly using javascript so i want V8's javascript performance. Mozilla is still a long way to reach V8's performance right?

Comment: For prism there is a catch : In addition to passing simple command line parameters, Prism can use a zipped bundle package to install a webapp. The bundle can hold additional resources currently limited to:

Application INI settings
Application icon
Script for the application chrome, not the web content. So thats mean i cant just bundle qooxdoo build folder and index.html inside there.

Comment: My apologies for the late response.  I wasn't getting notifications.  I'm not aware of any tools to use with Chrome.  I'm surprised that the web content (including Javascript files) can't be packages.  But, my experience with Mozilla Prism is very limited as I only briefly experimented.

Comment: Yeah that was a really downner , my best bet is to just pack everything as an XULRunner APP i guess?